# Correction for sample without replacement (unknown population)

Tags: statistics

I have to do a one-sample test for the mean with known population variance. 
Unfortunately, I now have to correct my mean variance.

Therefore I would use the formula "correction for a sample without replacement".

[Illustrated formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mbA6.jpg)

But I don't know the population size. Does anyone know how to correct the mean variance if the population ($N$) is unknown?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you don´t know the population size N there is only one way to handle the finite correction factor. It must be reasonable expected that $N$ is sufficiently large.  First let $N$ go to infinity:

$$\sigma_{\overline x}=\lim_{N\to \infty }\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt n}\cdot \sqrt{\frac{N-n}{N-1}}=\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt n}$$

And for a sufficiently large $N$ it can be approximated

$$\sigma_{\overline x}\approx\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt n}$$